# A variable containing an anonymous function is an object and callable

Tags: php, oop, closures, anonymous-function

It's confusing me, how can a variable be a callable object if I only assign it with a function.

If I execute this snippet:

```
$a = function () {};

if (is_object($a)) {
    echo "is Object\n";
}

if (is_callable($a)) {
    echo "is callable\n";
}
```

It outputs:

```
is Object
is callable
```

Comment: Precisely because you have assigned a function to it; a function is callable, and the mechanism by which a callable can be assigned to a variable is as an Object of type `Closure`, hence it is also an object

Comment: So Functioin is Object in PHP? oh... I see

Comment: No, anonymous functions,or [closures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php), are objects; functions like strlen() are not closures, nor are they objects

Answer (score 2):

Objects can define a [magic method `__invoke`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke), which makes an object *callable*. An object with such a method is both an object *and* callable. Anonymous functions use this mechanism under the hood; an anonymous function is actually an instance of [`Closure`](http://www.php.net/closure), though they're a bit special:

> Besides the methods listed here, this class also has an `__invoke` method. This is for consistency with other classes that implement calling magic, as this method is not used for calling the function.